# Dishwasher not draining water

Tags: plumbing, repair, dishwasher

I have a Bosch dishwasher that is 4 years old. Lately it has been leaving water at the bottom at the end of the cycle. Tried running the cycle again and it cleans the dishes but leaves water in the end. Any tips as to what is possibly wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If anything in the drain system is partially blocked it can cause poor draining. Have you given everything a good clean? First by hand, then a dishwasher cleaning product. Also the trap on the adjoining sink (assuming the dishwasher is connected like most I've seen) - inspect/clean or try putting a caustic soda based cleaner down it. If you've done all that it's time to start thinking about repair.

Comment: How is the drain line run?  Can you post some photos of the drain line?

Comment: @ChrisH that was it. A clogged drain pipe. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was not as bad as some had thought. It was a clogged drain pipe (black pipe in 2nd picture) and all I needed to do was remove it and unclog it. Apparently this is a very common problem. I found the answer [here](http://www.terrycaliendo.com/bosch-dishwasher-not-draining-leaving-standing-water-after-the-wash-cycle-completes/).

Answer (score 1):

The drain valve could be sticking. There is usually a solenoid that opens the drain valve at the end of the cycle and the water is pumped out instead of circulating.

If the solenoid or the valve is malfunctioning then water could be left after the cycle or the dishwasher doesn't fill as far as it should.

Experiment some more but it sounds like a repair is in your future.

Good luck!

Comment: Any pointers to what I can experiment with?

Comment: Well, my GE was not closing the drain valve all the way so when it filled at the start of a cycle it never got quite full. Then at the end of the cycle it never completely emptied. If you have the owners manual see if you can locate the drain valve. It should be close to the origin of the drain hose. Mine has a pretty simple solenoid that pulls in at the end of the cycle and then drops out and the spring closes the flapper valve. The solenoid was sticking and finally burned up. Then it wouldn't drain at all.

Comment: Usually you can advance the timer by hand to simulate the cycle until you get to the point where the drain valve opens. Then observe the valve in action to see if it is working.