# Dishwasher not draining

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Bosch dishwasher (modelnr: SMU69T42SK). It is no longer draing properly at the end of a cycle.

There is a [similar question here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90359/dishwasher-not-draining-water), which mentions a failing solenoid valve as a possible fault.

I don't think this is my issue, though, because when I put it on the quick (15m) rinse cycle, the first thing it does is pump out the water in the bottom without a problem (identified from sound of water in drain, verified by opening the door immediately after and seeing water has emptied).

I have [read here (sorry, Danish article)](https://cjdele.dk/opvaskemaskine-pumper-ikke-vand-ud#:%7E:text=Hvis%20afl%C3%B8bspumpen%20virker%2C%20men%20opvaskemaskinen,se%20om%20det%20afhj%C3%A6lper%20problemet.) that there may be a dirty or faulty "niveaukontrol" (level sensor, I think). From the symptoms the article describes, this sounds likely.

I have found the [parts drawings](https://www.bosch-home.dk/supportdetail/product/SMU69T42SK/01#/ProductCode=00611323/Tabs=section-spareparts/Togglebox=tb0435/Togglebox=tb0525/) (washing system subassembly, page 6), but I can't identify a level sensor. Also, I don't see a [float-like device in the bottom as in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPtfU1s1kEo)

Is it possible that my machine does not have a level sensor? How would it know it drained the water if not?

Any suggestions are of course very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I determined the cause of the problem. It was a failing solenoid valve ([part number 0404](https://www.bosch-home.dk/supportdetail/product/SMU69T42SK/01#/ProductCode=00611323/Tabs=section-spareparts/Togglebox=tb0404/Togglebox=tb0525/)) controlling the outflow from the plastic container on the left side (supposedly a heat exchanger).

The symptom of water in the bottom occurred after draining was complete (which, as it turns out, it successfully were) where the machine takes in some new water to the container. Presumably, this is not supposed to be full at this point, and so water entered into the main compartment by way of an overflow outlet (part no. 0402 in the parts drawing).

After ordering a new valve for 200 dkk and replacing the old one, my washer now works again.

Also, if doing this, be *sure* to unplug the washer. After changing the valve, I discovered it runs on mains voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Check the filter/strainer inside the dishwasher.
It may be clogged with debris or soap residue.
Read the owners manual to find how to remove and clean the filter/strainer

Comment: Quick rinse drain works for him and would not if there was crud in the drain.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I did that as the very first thing. The pump well as well including the turbidity sensor are now spotless.

Answer (score 1):

I often visit sites like repairclinic.com or ereplacementparts.com and look up my model of appliance. Find the list of replacement parts. It will often show which parts are bought most often for that model and you can then research to see if those parts will address your issue. A bit of reverse engineering, so to speak.

Glad you figgered it out.